# Create order from quote with existing payment method, but do not place payment?

Tags: magento2, orders, payment-methods, quote

I am working on a webhook endpoint that will take quotes and turn them into finished orders.

As part of this, I want to set the quotes payment method to a custom existing payment method, but I do not want it to "place" the payment; I just want the order to have the payment details.

I know I can pass "checkmo" as the payment method, but that is not a viable option for what I want. I need to pass the custom payment method.

Part of the order process is to place the payment, see `/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php` line 1176, `public function place()`

```
    public function place()
    {
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('sales_order_place_before', ['order' => $this]);
        $this->_placePayment();
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('sales_order_place_after', ['order' => $this]);
        return $this;
    }
```

How can I stop `$this->_placePayment()` from being triggered?

Comment: create around plugin and remove $this->_placePayment(); method from your plugin function and don't call original place() method with proceed().

Comment: @RonakChauhan can you show an example? I'm not sure how I'd use a plugin to remove the `placePayment()` call? Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "don't call original place() method with proceed()"

Answer (score 0):

`di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order">
        <plugin name="aroundPlaceMethod" type="<vendor>\<module>\Plugin\Model\Order" />
    </type>
</config>
```

`Order.php` (vendor/module/Plugin/Model)

```
<?php
namespace <vendor>>\<module>\Plugin\Model;

class Order
{
    /**
     * Place order Plugin
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function aroundPlace(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('sales_order_place_before', ['order' => $this]);
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('sales_order_place_after', ['order' => $this]);
        return $this;
    }
}
```